# Dapper, Insert record in SQLite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper, system.data.sqlite, dapper-contrib

I am trying to insert a record in a SQLite table, but the first fields stays `NULL`.

First I created a table in Ssqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests(id INTEGER, nr INTEGER);
```

Then I wrote this code (Target Framework: .NET 6.0):

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace ConsoleApp48
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
            sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True; ");
            sqlite_conn.Open();

            Test t;
            t = new Test() { id = 1, nr = 1 };
            sqlite_conn.Insert<Test>(t);
            t = new Test() { id = 5, nr = 5 };
            sqlite_conn.Insert<Test>(t);

            sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int nr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After this the contents of my database is:

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Test(id INTEGER, nr INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE Tests(id INTEGER, nr INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Tests VALUES(NULL,1);
INSERT INTO Tests VALUES(NULL,5);
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

Table `Test` also exists, but that is a minor issue. I thought table should have the same name as the class, so I did create the table as `Test`, but on failure I created table `Tests` with same structure.

The real question is the two NULL values in the created records. Why is the field `id` not updated with the correct value (`1` or `5`) ?

I tried finding if I am missing something obvious, but failing to find it, I created this minimal reproduceable example.

Info on the `using`s:

- Dapper.Contrib: version 2.0.78
- System.Data.Sqlite.Core: version 1.0.116

Comment: if you change the column name from _id_ to something else then it works. Not sure why, still looking for the reason (are you using _dapper-contrib_ right?)

Comment: A column named `id` may have special semantics to it. Not sure, though, how usage of System.Data.SQLite in conjunction with Dapper may lead to the observed behavior.

Comment: It is something coming from the extension because a bare bone dapper _cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO (id, nr) values (@id, @nr)", t);_ works as expected

Comment: @steve: "(are you using dapper-contrib right?)"   How is right? , But as Fildor said `id` does something special... 

Comment: I can confirm that changing `id` to (i.e.) `i`  solves the problem.

Comment: I mean this extension: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib but I see now you are using this one: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions

Comment: I do have version 2.0.78, so I am using: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib ?

Comment: There, the source code doesn't lie. The KeyPropertiesCache method is used inside the Insert code to find all the computed columns and the key columns. In that code there is a check for _id_ and if they find a column with that name without key attribute they add it to a collection of columns that are excluded from the building of the insert query

Comment: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/blob/cf24f6bdc577b1e071c3764ddfb2cf3382531405/src/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L100

Comment: I added an issue on Githib (see: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/issues/140) maybe some author can explain... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a primary key solved the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, nr INTEGER);
```

(Which reminds me I should always do define such a thing, even when I am having only a small number of records.....